# building connection string dynamically

Tags: c#, .net

Having these items:

```
ConnDatabase
ConnServer
ConnUsername
ConnPassword
```

as strings, what is the best way to generate a SQL server connection string as can be found in a web.config file?

PS:

This is actually (most likely) intended for dapper

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to write web.config at runtime, it is security risk, so just using SQLConnectionStringbuilder object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx

Comment: I only said as in a Web.config file ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're building a SQL connection string then there is a dedicated framework class for that: [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)

Here's a snippet from the MSDN article:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "(local)";
builder["integrated Security"] = true;
builder["Initial Catalog"] = "AdventureWorks;NewValue=Bad";
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);
```

which results in this safely (quoted) value of:

```
Source=(local);Initial Catalog="AdventureWorks;NewValue=Bad";Integrated Security=True
```

This class also helps with parsing connection strings, which can be very useful (if not more useful than building them, IMO):

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
var dataSource = builder["Data Source"];
```

Comment: Other builders & howtos: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks that's what I use in the first place to disassemble it in another application.